# How to show image in the div, onhover some element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to recreate the effect that is here https://jumpshare.com/ in the section 'Capture and share anything quickly', when you hover on the left text, in the right blcok appears other image. I know ho to do it if the elemnet is in the same block, but how can I do it if they are in the separate divs?

I TRIED THIS:

```
<div href="#" class='text'>
     Hover me
 </div>
<div class='image'>
    Show me
</div>

image{
  display: none;
}
.text:hover .image{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: You need javascript for that. Did you try anything so far?

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? **Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)**. Before posting, *you should have researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself*. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can help.

Comment: why arte you just putting minuses and didn't try to help?!!! If I write question on stackoverflow it means that I tried all possible variants

Comment: It the best solution from your side just to judge somebody and don't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website you listed uses a separate css class that is added to each div when the user hovers. They titled their class "selected." See below on how to add and remove classes using jquery to achieve this effect.

**CSS**

First, create the stylings you'd like to apply to your div when someone hovers over it:

```
.selected {
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: blue;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

**jquery**

Then, make a jquery function for hovering on each div that applies the "selected" class upon hovering and removes it when hovering onto antoher div.

```
$('.hoverdivs div').on('hover', function() {
    var selected = $('.hoverdivs div.selected');
    selected.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

**HTML**

And here is what the HTML looks like for my hypothetical code:

```
<div class="hoverdivs">
    <div class="hoverdiv1">
    </div>
    <div class="hoverdiv2">
    </div>
    <div class="hoverdiv3">
    </div>
    <div class="hoverdiv4">
    </div>
</div>
```

Be sure to apply your initial formatting to the divs and fill them with content! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Solution no.1 it to use `CSS`:

```
.text:hover + .image {
   display: block;
}
```

`+` means I call neighbor selector which selects the element next to the subject element. `Note: this only works if the elements sits beside each other.`

Solution no.2 is to use `JavaScript` | `jQuery`:

```
// when pointer hovers the element
document.querySelector(".text").addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
     document.querySelector(".image").style.display = "block";
});

// when pointer leaves the element
document.querySelector(".text").addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
     document.querySelector(".image").style.display = "none";
});

// jQuery: onenter
$(".text").on("mouseenter", function () {
    $(".image").css("display", "block");
});

// jQuery: onleave
$(".text").on("mouseenter", function () {
    $(".image").css("display", "none");
});
```

since you are trying to copy a feature in your example website you should attach multiple event listeners that display different images.

hope that helps.